# How to change from one case to another (many to many make it many to one) using lstm in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of 140 rows with 5 columns. Every 5 values in the row represents the input. The target for every row is variables. How can I make it many to one or many to one in Matlab?

Comment: clear;
clc;
close all;
y1 = [14 5 5 4 3;
15 6 6 5 4;
15 5 6 4 4;
15 5 7 5 3;
16 5 7 4 4;
15 5 7 4 4]'
y={y1(:,1);y1(:,2);y1(:,3);y1(:,4);y1(:,5);y1(:,6)}'
% y=y';
t=categorical([ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ])'
Labels=t;
inputSize = 5;
numHiddenUnits1= 100;
numHiddenUnits2= 100;
numClasses = 6;
this mine code for matlab

Comment: Please add this code to the question.